# What is the use of qGetPtrHelper in this example?

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I was reading [this article](https://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Dpointer) and I came across the following definition (in [qglobal.h](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/master/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h#line2416)):

```
template <typename T> static inline T *qGetPtrHelper(T *ptr) { return ptr; }
template <typename Wrapper> static inline typename Wrapper::pointer qGetPtrHelper(const Wrapper &p) { return p.data(); }    

#define Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Class) \
    inline Class##Private* d_func() { return reinterpret_cast<Class##Private *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); } \
    inline const Class##Private* d_func() const { return reinterpret_cast<const Class##Private *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); } \
    friend class Class##Private;
```

I understand that the macro defines common functions for classes that utilize the D-pointer/pImpl pattern. However I don't quite grasp the need for the `qGetPtrHelper` function. It just returns a copy of a pointer that will be casted right away. Couldn't the `ptr` variable casted directly without this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

d_ptr can be a smart pointer (QScopedPointer, for instance) and in that case it can't be just passed to reinterpret_cast: d_func() would have to access the internal pointer using a member function or so requiring two versions of the macro (in fact, there used to be two before qGetPtrHelper existed). What qGetPtrHelper does is to trigger an implicit cast of a smart pointer, when passed as the argument, to a raw one, thus eliminating the need for special handling.

Comment: Oh there are two of them, I just omitted the other one because I thought it wasn't relevant to the question (I didn't understand that one either, but I thought I'll ask another question if I still don't get it after this one). I think this nicely explains it. Thanks.